# Singleton in Kotlin with Dagger (@Singleton) or Object

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, dagger-2

What's the best approach for having a `Singleton` with a few `LiveData` for observing and posting?

**Object:**

```
object EventsObj {

    private val _actionLiveData = MutableLiveData<...>()
    val actionLiveData: LiveData<...> = _actionLiveData

    fun postActionEvent(value: ...) {
        _actionLiveData.postValue(value)
    }
    ... //few more LiveDatas following the same logic
}
```

**or Dagger:**

```
@Singleton
class EventsClass
@Inject constructor() {

    private val _actionLiveData = MutableLiveData<...>()
    val actionLiveData: LiveData<...> = _actionLiveData

    fun postActionEvent(value: ...) {
        _actionLiveData.postValue(value)
    }

    ... //few more LiveDatas following the same logic
}
```

**Use:**

```
@Inject
lateinit var eventsClass: EventsClass

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    eventsClass.actionLiveData.observe(this, ...)
    eventsClass.postActionEvent(...)

    EventsObj.actionLiveData.observe(this, ...)
    EventsObj.postActionEvent(...)
}
```

Comment: There is a good chance you're looking for an EventBus and not LiveData in this scenario

Comment: True, for example like this: https://gist.github.com/takahirom/f2dbcc3053adfd87ac7e321d95a23021. But which is the better approach, Dagger or Object? I've always used Dagger in this situations but if I want to fire from a ViewModel I'll have to inject it "everywhere" (let say I have some BaseViewModel dependent code). With an Object I can post and observe in "static way" no injection needed. I would like to know the down sides of this "static usage".

Comment: For clarity `@Singleton` in Dagger has no direct relationship with an actual singleton class it is simply a `@Scope` annotation class provided with the library and only has meaning with regards of scoping to the component i.e one instance per component. Kotlin `object` classes are true singletons.  If you create your own ViewModelFactory, where you have access to the ViewModel constructor this can all easilly be done with dagger. Downside of singletons - testing and reasoning about state.

Comment: Actually I've all the `ViewModelFactory` logic for creating `ViewModels` and also  the dynamic `SavedStateHandle` ( `@AssistedInject.Factory`) logic too. I was just wondering If in a situation where I have an Object class (with no dependencies) to fire some events that can be listen in a desired `lifescopeOwner`, if injecting in a `BaseViewModel` would be overkill comparing with static access (all child VMs will have to `@Inject`). I would like to know the downsides because for me, the static access instead of constructor injection is a plus (in this situation only of course).

Answer (score 1):

Working with Oject Kotlin will simplify your life. Its easier to call. There is no need to create dependencies and write additional code.

If you use Dagger, you will get more flexibility. Because You can replace the code for testing. And in the case when you will need to replace one implementation with another, you will have to change the code only in one place.